# How to set environment path to folder in my documents directory on mac

Tags: python-3.x, environment-variables, hyperledger-fabric

Hello I am working on a hyper ledger fabric project using python

I am running into an error on my program which requires me to set an environment path

below is the error given :

```
configtxgen not in PATH.
Configtx is empty
```

now I know the fix for this, it requires me setting an environment path to a file called

```
configtx.yaml
```

its location on my Mac is

```
documents/blockchain/fabric-sdk-py/test/fixtures/e2e_cli/configtx.yaml
```

please how do I set an environment path towards this file

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How you set an env var depends on your shell and whether you are running the program from a shell prompt or some other way (e.g., double-clicking on an application icon). Assuming you're using a POSIX shell like bash or zsh you would type something like this:

```
export VAR_NAME="$HOME/documents/blockchain/fabric-sdk-py/test/fixtures/e2e_cli/configtx.yaml"
```

You would normally put that statement in a file like *~/.bashrc* so it is set each time you start an interactive shell.

P.S., If the documentation for the application you're using doesn't tell you how to do this I would open an issue suggesting such instructions be added.